# Assigning roles to a user in registration process [yii (users + auth)]

Tags: php, authentication, yii, roles

Im using users + auth modules in Yii.
I've made 3 roles in auth using administration:

```
auth/role/
```

1. Admin
2. Company
3. Other

Also, in users module

```
user/profileField
```

I've made one profile field which will determinate in registration page, what account you want to make

```
[boolean: true="Company" false="Other"]
```

*Admin acc can be only created in module*

I want to assign roles based on this field in registration process.
I assume i should write this in this method (?):

```
/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php:
public function actionRegistration(){...
...
 if ($model->save()) {
                        $profile->user_id=$model->id;
                        ....my role assign here ?...
                        $profile->save();
 ...
```

btw: is it classy to change /user/controllers/RegistrationController.php directly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign roles to users use:

```
Yii::app()->authManager->assign($role,$userId);
```

[as explained here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#defining-authorization-hierarchy)